# WhatsApp Cloud API Receiving Images from Users Error

Tags: json, express, whatsapp

I am currently working on a project to have users submission of reporting an event. This event can be reported using images sent to the WhatsApp bot. On testing, I saw an opportunity to retrieve the attachments via the endpoint

```bash
curl -X GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/2962383147393274' -H "Authorization: $BEARER_TOKEN" | jq
```

The response in JSON:

```json
{
  "url": "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=2962383147393274&ext=1659478078&hash=ATvilCALzGPUvP9AwBAIqOMLFUVs4OZ5Gk50s76SKkJJqA",
  "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
  "sha256": "fd5a860f1ac47aa81b825803ceb3fc88debb725587f5b8c5161c163d2484406b",
  "file_size": 109401,
  "id": "2962383147393274",
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp"
}
```

The issue is when going to the URL, it gives a 500 issue and I am unsure how to go about displaying these images in a dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access media by direct its URL, you have to pass the authentication token in the header, So there is a next step you are missing is [Download Media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#download-media),

- `URL` replace the media URL with this
- `ACCESS_TOKEN` replace your access token

```
curl -X GET 'URL' \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' > media_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Alright so I had the same issue and found out the solution.

TL;DR: You need to pass the User-Agent when making the GET request to download the media. The value of User-Agent must mimick cURL, like "curl/7.64.1". This will work.

Longer version:

You need to pass a "valid user-agent". This is undocumented. But the download clearly works when calling the endpoint using the `curl` binary. So I figured I'd just use the same UA (User-Agent) that curl is using.

I'm using the `excon` gem in Ruby to perform the request, like this:

```rb
    # "body" is the response body from the previous request to the /MEDIA_ID endpoint
    response = Excon.get(body['url'], { 
      headers: {
        'Authorization' => "Bearer #{your_fb_token}",
        'User-Agent' => 'curl/7.64.1'
      }
    })
```

And it works, the media contents (binary) are returned in the request.

My conclusion is that the User-Agent header is very important here (and it's just sad that it is undocumented). Using Excon's default UA, I get a 302 response with the `Location` header pointing to `https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser`.
By using a real browser UA, I get a 200 response but it's an HTML page. Using the `curl/...` UA is the only that actually returns the media payload.

Comment: I've encountered the same situation and adding the User-Agent solved my issue too