# Whatsapp cloud API Media URL doesnot work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, whatsapp

I am using whatsapp cloud API webhook to receive customer messages. When customer sends a media object like image or video, I am able to receive media id. On sending GET request to **https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/MEDIA_ID** using the same access token used on webhooks, I am able to get the URL but on opening the URL it shows ***Sorry, something went wrong.***

I have tested with different media IDs but all URLs shows the same page attached below.

[image]

Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to make a request for the media URL, that includes the access token again. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#retrieve-media-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WhatsApp Cloud API Receiving Images from Users Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214351/whatsapp-cloud-api-receiving-images-from-users-error)

Comment: Yes thank you @CBroe and turivishal

Answer (score 2):

You need send your token try to test it in postman:

```bash
curl -X GET 'URL' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' > file
```

Link to docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#retrieve-media-url

[image: screenshot from docs]

Comment: This type of information should be posted as comments.

Comment: @DrashtiKheni this should not be a comment - it's actually the correct solution. Still I improved the formatting and wording a bit

Answer (score 0):

I've written an asynchronous function in Node.js to download and save media using Axios. Feel free to use and modify it for your projects!

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const randomstring = require('randomstring');

/**
 * Downloads and saves media from Facebook Graph API.
 * @param {string} token - Facebook access token.
 * @param {string} mediaId - Facebook media ID.
 * @returns {string} - Path to the saved media file.
 */
async function downloadAndSaveMedia(token, mediaId) {
    try {
        const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/${mediaId}/`;
        // Retrieving URL 
        const getUrl = await axios(url, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + token
            }
        });

        const config = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: getUrl?.data?.url, // Pass the URL received from media ID
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        };

        const response = await axios(config);
        const ext = response.headers['content-type'].split("/")[1];

        const randomSt = randomstring.generate();
        const savingPath = `${__dirname}/../client/public/meta-media/${randomSt}`;
        fs.writeFileSync(`${savingPath}.${ext}`, response.data);
        return `${randomSt}.${ext}`;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error downloading media:', error);
    }
}

// Example usage
const token = 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN';
const mediaId = 'YOUR_MEDIA_ID';

downloadAndSaveMedia(token, mediaId)
    .then((filePath) => console.log(`Media downloaded and saved at: ${filePath}`))
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));
```